# Checking if first derivative is zero at a given point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function

```
V[a_, h_, tau_] := (Sqrt[3]/2) h (Sqrt[3] a + h/3 tau)^2
```

now I want to check, whether its first derivative is zero in a given point. Say for the solution

```
{a -> 8.47344, h -> 1.67718, tau -> 12.9438}
```

I tried

```
Dt[V[a, h, t], a, h, tau] /. {a -> 8.47344, h -> 1.67718, tau -> 12.9438}
```

Is this the proper way to show that? I use `V` in a system of equations, which I am trying to solve with [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @rcollyer beat my by 5 seconds :)

Comment: @tkott, I win again. :P

Comment: @Martin are you sure you want `Dt` instead of `D`? If you want `Dt`, then you will need to specify all combinations of `Dt[h, tau]` through rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three variables, so the "first derivative" is a little ambiguous.  You can take a derivative with respect to one of these and feed the solution in directly, e.g.

```
D[V[a, h, tau], a] /. {a -> 8.47344, h -> 1.67718, tau -> 12.9438}
```

(Spoiler: none of them are zero)

When you take the total derivative `Dt[V[a, h, t], a, h, tau]`, it gives you a result in terms of the relationship between the variables, such as `Dt[a,h]` or `Dt[h,tau]`.  You have to specify what these are from you original problem.  Substituting in numbers directly gives nonsensical expression such as `Dt[8.47344, 1.67718]`.  You can't take the derivative of a number with respect to a number.

You could also ask Mathematica when one of the first derivatives is zero:

```
Solve[D[V[a, h, tau], a] == 0]
```

Comment: You don't have to calculate the derivatives one by one. To calculate all the first order partial derivatives at the specified point in one go you can do something like `D[V[a, h, tau], {{a, h, tau}}] /. {a -> 8.47344, h -> 1.67718, tau -> 12.9438}`